# How can I test some feature in all major mobile devices(android, apple etc) in minimal amount of time?

Tags: manual-testing, test-management, test-planning, test-strategy

Someone asked me what strategy will you follow to test some important features of your application before prod release so that it will work on almost all the mobile devices?
I gave Suggestions like:
BrowserStack, Saucelabs.
Setup Mobile testing labs.
Get the customer base of mobile devices as per area/region.

But he didn't satisfy with these points.
Can someone throw some light on this?

> I know this is kinda subjective question but I post hereafter
>   searching about this a lot on to internet already.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We had the same issue in our past. For some reasons we managed that somehow. Because beside testing with simulators we also tested with real devices (since real devices have different behaviour than simulators).

**First: Made an overview about the devices with the help of statistic webpage**

In case of using real devices you have to consider that you are using:

- Different devices (Samsung, Apple, Huawei, Xiaomi, Motorola...)
- Mobile Versions (iOS 12.1, iOS 11.4, iOS 9.3, 8.0 Oreo, 7.0 Nougat...)
- Different usage of mobile and devices in different countries (e.g. percentage in Germany, Spain, France...)

Of course the business department wanted to test them all, but due to time circumstances it was not possible. Hence we focussed on the most relevant ones. We made a research via Statcounter:

All the datas are free via: [GS Statcounter](https://gs.statcounter.com/)

**Second: For overview purposes create browsermatrix and reduce the unrelevant ones:**

Due to research in Statcounter we focussed on the most relevant ones and reduced the unnecessary devices/mobile versions.

In this case a browsermatrix like this helped in our case:

[image]

I know that this is just a small advice but in our case it helped to decrease the amount of  testing devices. Of course there is a risk that some devices are not running / working. But in our case we couldn't test all combinations.

**Third: Aske the business department for help before Prod with real devices**

Some people are willing to help before Go-Live. Especially the business department was willing to help us since everybody has his private device ;-)

Answer (score 0):

A good mobile app testing services provider has different options available according to time at offer for mobile testing.

If a quick test run is to be performed on the major mobile devices/configurations, then below techniques can be followed.

- Text should be checked on one device as it will be same on the others as well. So only the layout/breaks need to be cross checked.
- It would be very beneficial if automation suites can be created to test the app/website on devices. Though it will might take some time to build but once done, it will reduce the time and effort to test exponentially.
- If there is a feature or functionality which is redundant, should be tested once and can be bypassed on other devices.

Comment: If it's the same application, all the features are "reduntant". And if the texts are localized, you have to check that you have translated them all both on android and ios.

Answer (score 0):

You should get a good understanding of widely used mobile platforms and form factors around the world. The device matrix shared by @dbmunich is a good one. There are many factors to consider before arriving on a similar matrix. There's a vast difference while you strategise testing of a native application versus a hybrid application.

1. Automate your sanity and Regression test cases.
2. Derive your Mobile Device test matrix
3. Set up a virtual or physical mobile farm or subscribe to a similar managed service
4. Run your sanity tests nightly on your mobile farm

Keep updating your Mobile matrix and have an up to date mobile farm for testing.

Don't test only on the release day. Integrate continuously, Deploy continuously and test continuously. Fail fast.